# SQL 'while' condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE dollars (
  price decimal,
  amount decimal
);
```

Each record have price(1,23 USD) and amount(0.2). How I can select records until amount doesn't equal 5 or more.

For example:

1. Price: 4, amount: 2.5
2. Price: 2 , amount: 1.5
3. Price: 5, amount: 3

Total 3 items with summary amount 7.

Comment: i feel you need where condition.
while is a loop which runs till a condition is met.here you cannot specify such condition.

Comment: do you mean loop through each record and store amount sum? use a well defined `where` clause instead

Comment: should the query pick random records from the table? in any way, the solution is to use window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have unique key on "price" column?

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    dol.id, 
    dol.price,
    dol.amount, 
    (SELECT sum(amount) FROM public.dollars dol2 WHERE dol2.price <= dol.price) AS sum_amount
FROM
    public.dollars dol
WHERE
   (SELECT floor(sum(amount)) FROM public.dollars dol2 WHERE dol2.price <= dol.price) <= 5
ORDER BY price ASC;
```

Of course you can change "order by" condition if you want to select records with e.g. lower id, not price.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a WHERE condition is needed rather than a while
something like

```
   SELECT * FROM dollars 
   WHERE amount < 5
```